# BlockControls not showing floating (show up in the top toolbar)

Tags: block-editor

I have a simple Gutenberg block that styles text as a [post it note](https://github.com/prtksxna/a-sticky-note/). It uses a `BlockControls` to show some basic formatting like alignment and text styles. Since I upgraded to 5.5, to `BlockControls` doesn't show up floating over the widget. However, if I change my setting to be *Top Toolbar* it shows up on top and functions normally ([setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc0Kw.png)). Note that the `InspectorControls` are showing up just fine. Here is my `index.js':

```js
/* eslint no-unused-vars: 0 */
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import {
    RichText,
    AlignmentToolbar,
    BlockControls,
    InspectorControls,
    ColorPalette,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { PanelBody, PanelRow, FontSizePicker } from '@wordpress/components';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

registerBlockType( 'sticky-note/sticky-note', {
    title: 'Sticky note',
    icon: 'pressthis',
    category: 'layout',
    styles: [
        {
            name: 'paper',
            label: 'Paper', // TODO: What to do here? Use _x
            isDefault: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'flat',
            label: 'Flat',
        },
    ],
    supports: {
        align: true,
        alignWide: false,
        reusable: false,
        lightBlockWrapper: true,
    },
    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'p',
        },
        alignment: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'none',
        },
        color: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '#f9eeaa',
        },
        fontSize: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 16,
        },
    },
    example: {
        attributes: {
            content: 'Type something…',
            alignment: 'center',
        },
    },
    edit( props ) {
        const {
            attributes: { content, alignment, color, fontSize },
            setAttributes,
        } = props;

        const onChangeContent = ( newContent ) => {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        };

        const onChangeAlignment = ( newAlignment ) => {
            props.setAttributes( {
                alignment: newAlignment === undefined ? 'none' : newAlignment,
            } );
        };

        const onChangeColor = ( newColor ) => {
            props.setAttributes( {
                color: newColor === undefined ? '#f9eeaa' : newColor,
            } );
        };

        const fontSizes = [
            {
                name: __( 'Normal' ),
                slug: 'normal',
                size: 16,
            },
            {
                name: __( 'Medium' ),
                slug: 'medium',
                size: 20,
            },
            {
                name: __( 'Large' ),
                slug: 'large',
                size: 36,
            },
            {
                name: __( 'Huge' ),
                slug: 'huge',
                size: 48,
            },
        ];
        const fallbackFontSize = 20;

        const onFontSizeChange = ( newFontSize ) => {
            props.setAttributes( {
                fontSize:
                    newFontSize === undefined ? fallbackFontSize : newFontSize,
            } );
        };

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    <BlockControls>
                        <AlignmentToolbar
                            value={ alignment }
                            onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                        />
                    </BlockControls>
                }
                {
                    <InspectorControls>
                        <PanelBody title={ __( 'Color' ) }>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <ColorPalette
                                    disableCustomColors={ false }
                                    value={ color }
                                    onChange={ onChangeColor }
                                    clearable={ true }
                                />
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                        <PanelBody title={ __( 'Font size' ) }>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <FontSizePicker
                                    fontSizes={ fontSizes }
                                    fallbackFontSize={ fallbackFontSize }
                                    value={ fontSize }
                                    onChange={ onFontSizeChange }
                                />
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                    </InspectorControls>
                }
                <RichText
                    tagName="p"
                    className="wp-block-sticky-note-sticky-note"
                    style={ {
                        textAlign: alignment,
                        backgroundColor: color,
                        fontSize,
                    } }
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                    value={ content }
                />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: ( props ) => {
        return (
            <RichText.Content
                className={ `sticky-note-${ props.attributes.alignment }` }
                style={ {
                    fontSize: props.attributes.fontSize,
                    backgroundColor: props.attributes.color,
                } }
                tagName="p"
                value={ props.attributes.content }
            />
        );
    },
} );
```

This is what the block looks like in the editor, see the floating block controls are missing:
[image: block without toolbar]

But they show up fine and work when the top toolbar setting is selected:
[image: top toolbar working fine]

I have tried removing all the CSS but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I have tested it up to 5.2, where it was working fine. You can find the entire code base on [Github](https://github.com/prtksxna/a-sticky-note).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tested your [code](https://github.com/prtksxna/a-sticky-note), and it seems that the issue happened because you enabled the `lightBlockWrapper` support for your block type (i.e. `lightBlockWrapper: true` in the `support` property), which then doesn't wrap the block in `.wp-block` — check a [sample diff here](https://www.diffchecker.com/FnrBD8um).

And to fix the issue, you'd only need to disable the `lightBlockWrapper` support — use `lightBlockWrapper: false` or just don't set `lightBlockWrapper` at all..

Comment: Wow! Thanks Sally CJ, that worked. I am curious to know how you figured it out. I can't seem to find any documentation on that property. I don't even know why I added it (must've copied it from a tutorial).

Comment: I also couldn't find any documentation on that property, but I just thought that the `lightBlockWrapper` was a little suspicious, so I disabled it in the `build/index.js` file, and then tested it. (I did not figure it out at first sight/attempt, though; I also did some other similar tests earlier on)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use same code structure among the edit and save methods. The RIchText need to be waraped inside div.

```
<div>
<RichText.Content
 className={ `sticky-note-${ props.attributes.alignment }` }
 style={ {
     fontSize: props.attributes.fontSize,backgroundColor: props.attributes.color,
  } }
  tagName="p"
  value={ props.attributes.content }/>
</div>
```